# Spark get column names of nested json

Tags: java, json, apache-spark-sql, nested

I'm trying to get column names from a nested JSON via DataFrames. The schema is given below:

```
root
 |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sw1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sw2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sw3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sw420: string (nullable = true)
 |-- headers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- endDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- startDate: string (nullable = true)
```

I can get the column names "body" and "header" with df.columns() but when I try to get the column names from the body (ex: Sw1, Sw2,...) with df.select("body").columns it always give me the body column.

Any suggestion? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the question is how to find the nested column names, you can do this by inspecting the `schema` of the DataFrame.  The schema is represented as a [`StructType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) which can fields of other [`DataType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType) objects (included other nested structs).  If you want to discover all the fields you'll have to walk this tree recursively.  For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
def findFields(path: String, dt: DataType): Unit = dt match {
  case s: StructType => 
    s.fields.foreach(f => findFields(path + "." + f.name, f.dataType))
  case other => 
    println(s"$path: $other")
}
```

This walks the tree and prints out all the leaf fields and their type:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize("""{"a": {"b": 1}}""" :: Nil))
findFields("", df.schema)

prints: .a.b: LongType
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. It will help me a lot but i'm using java. Do you have any idea for doing it in java ? I'm not comfortable with scala...

Comment: So I tried to do it in java. If I understand your code, your using the method fields() on the StructTypes and then findFields() on each StructTypes returned by fields(). With the Java API, if I use fields() on a StructType, it returns a FieldType so I'm not able to use findFields on it ...

Comment: Ok I succeeded getting the column values from body. I just had to cast my StructField to DataType and then call fields() on it. Thanks a lot Michael :)

Answer (score 1):

If the nested json has an array of StructTypes, then the following code can be used (the below code is extension to the code given by Michael Armbrust)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def findFields(path: String, dt: DataType): Unit = dt match {
  case s: StructType => 
    s.fields.foreach(f => findFields(path + "." + f.name, f.dataType))
  case s: ArrayType => 
    findFields(path, s.elementType)
  case other => 
    println(s"$path")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the nested column names please use code like below :

From main method call like below:

```
findFields(df,df.schema)
```

Method:

```
def findFields(df:DataFrame,dt: DataType) = 
{
    val fieldName = dt.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields
    for (value <- fieldName) 
    {
      val colNames = value.productElement(1).asInstanceOf[StructType].fields
      for (f <- colNames)
      {
         println("Inner Columns of "+value.name+" -->>"+f.name)
      }
   }
```

}

Note: This will work only when both first set of columns are struct type.

Answer (score -2):

Very simple: `df.select("body.Sw1", "body.Sw2")`

Comment: I don't want to specify "Sw1" and "Sw2" manually. The idea is to get column values (Sw1, Sw2, ...) programatically and iterable these column names to do selects.